# Laravel Schedule - AppSettings from Azure Portal

Tags: php, laravel, azureportal

I'm running a laravel app on Azure (App service on linux) and I have a few settings set in the portal itself like:

```
DB_DATABASE=mydbname
DB_USERNAME=mydbuser
DB_PASSWORD=mydbuserpwd
```

These values are NOT in the .env file.

It is working as expected for the app, the values are correctly read however, the [scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling) is not reading them and is using the default values from the database.php config file.

Adding these settings to the .env file resolves the problem but it is obviously not a real solution. Does anyone has encountered this issue?

Comment: Have you updated the physical path to public in Azure Portal ?

Answer (score 0):

> Laravel Schedule - AppSettings from Azure Portal

As per this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common?tabs=portal#configure-app-settings),

App Service uses the --env flag (.env file) to set the container's environment variable when passing app settings to Linux apps and custom containers.

- Environment variables from .env file are added into the app environment at Startup of the app.
- In Laravel App, the app settings are obtained as runtime environment variables.
- As per [Fikayo Adepoju](https://coderonfleek.medium.com/hosting-a-laravel-application-on-azure-web-app-b55e12514c46),
  In Step 8 of **Adding your .env file**, he suggests not to exclude the .env variables.

***References taken from***

[Laravel Deployment on App Service Linux](https://azureossd.github.io/2022/04/22/PHP-Laravel-deploy-on-App-Service-Linux-copy/index.html)

Environment Configuration [1](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/configuration#environment-configuration) ,[2](https://faun.pub/how-to-deploy-your-php-stack-based-laravel-web-application-on-azure-app-service-from-vs-code-e5692531aecd) and [3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-php?pivots=platform-linux#access-environment-variables)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using cron to run the scheduler?

We had a similar issue and we managed to solve it by sourcing the /etc/profile first and then calling `schdule:run` in the crontab.

`* * * * * BASH_ENV=/etc/profile php /site/wwwroot/artisan schedule:run`

Answer (score -1):

I hope my answer will help you to find out the solutions. I got same issue and try to find out the solutions from couple of days.

So, I assume you install cron and created one file which called `crontab`.

crontab has below code:

```
* *    * * *   root    cd {your app path} && BASH_ENV=/etc/profile bash -c "php artisan schedule:run >> output.txt"
```

`BASH_ENV=/etc/profile` is your all configuration settings which Azure is not getting after running cron. `bash -c` is binding your command in bash terminal, as I was checked my terminal and I am in bash terminal.
You have to change shell as `/bin/bash` as we are using bash terminal in Azure linux. The `*` symbol is often referred to as an asterisk.